# Android: setcontentview lead to runtimeexception

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, runtimeexception

I have a main activity (for sign up and log in) that has a button labeled (forget password) to open a new Forget password activity, while debugging I discovered that:

setContentView(R.layout.forgetpassword);

throws runtimeexception

What is wrong ?

ForgetParsePassword.java

```
     package com.parse.starter;
     import com.parse.ParseException;
     import com.parse.ParseUser;
     import com.parse.RequestPasswordResetCallback;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.text.TextUtils;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.Toast;

public class ForgetParsePassword extends Activity{
EditText et_forgetpassword = null;
Button btn_submitforgetpassword = null;
String password = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.forgetpassword);

    et_forgetpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_forget);
    btn_submitforgetpassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submitforgetpassword);

    btn_submitforgetpassword.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            password = et_forgetpassword.getText().toString();
            checkEmailID();


        }
    });

}

protected void checkEmailID() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        et_forgetpassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
    } else if (!password.contains("@")) {
        et_forgetpassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
    }
    else
        forgotPassword(password);
}

public void forgotPassword(String email) {
    //postEvent(new UserForgotPasswordStartEvent());
    ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground(email, new UserForgotPasswordCallback());
}

private class UserForgotPasswordCallback extends RequestPasswordResetCallback{
    public UserForgotPasswordCallback(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully sent link to your email for reset Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to sent link to your email for reset Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }       
}
```

}

Logcat:

```
03-08 13:54:40.513: D/dalvikvm(1317): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 302K, 12% free 2983K/3360K, paused 47ms, total 50ms
03-08 13:54:41.473: D/gralloc_goldfish(1317): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-08 13:54:42.933: D/dalvikvm(1317): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 248K, 10% free 3249K/3572K, paused 38ms, total 47ms
03-08 13:54:44.783: W/Resources(1317): Converting to int: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x11 "textEmailAddress" a=2 r=0x7f04000a}
03-08 13:54:44.783: D/AndroidRuntime(1317): Shutting down VM
03-08 13:54:44.783: W/dalvikvm(1317): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad0ba8)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 1317
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parse.starter/com.parse.starter.ForgetParsePassword}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at com.parse.starter.ForgetParsePassword.onCreate(ForgetParsePassword.java:25)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     ... 11 more
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     ... 24 more
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "textEmailAddress"
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:255)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1000)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:56)
03-08 13:54:45.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     ... 27 more
03-08 13:54:49.793: I/Process(1317): Sending signal. PID: 1317 SIG: 9
```

forgetpassword.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="@string/email"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_forget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="@string/e"
    android:inputType="@string/textemail" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_submitforgetpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_forget"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="@string/submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your logcat here and also post your forgetpassword activity

Comment: post the error, please

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike When I hit forgot password button I get exit from the application, instead of opening forgot password activity with its own layout for password reset

Comment: Post the contents of R.layout.forgetpassword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your layout.  This line is incorrect.

```
   android:inputType="@string/textemail" >
```

Please see the documentation, here:

[inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)